# how to iterate an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a onclick event that basically passes information to a query to determine how many records to show and which record to show.

I basically need to iterate $number each time the button is clicked.  Any ideas?

```
"Select * FROM tablename LIMIT $_POST['count'],1"
```

As it stands, $number = $('.result').length; either equals 0 or 2, so it will only show up to two records...

```
$(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var  number = 0;
     for (var i=0; i < number; i++) {


    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/x_files/getNext.php",
       data: {"count":$number},
       success: function(results){
         $('#results').html(results);
       }
     });

}
number++;
  });

});
```

Comment: What value do you want it to have?

Comment: Iterate over what ? to you want iterate over the result that you get back or iterante the number of times you make ajax call ?

Comment: @Anand Iterate the number of times you make the ajax call.  Initially, $number = 0 because there are no results (I have to click to get a result)...after my first click, $number = 1 because there is one results that was brought back...I need to then increment $number by 1 the next time the click occurs, then increment by 1 each time the button is clicked

Comment: you can use for loop and place the ajax call inside for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting back an array of object, you could use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or standard for loop

Did I understand you correctly ?

**UPDATE**

```
//global or store in a dom element
var  number = 0;
$('#showMore').click(function(event) {
for(var i =0;i < number ;i++){
  //ajax call
}
//increment number now
number++;
});
```

Comment: I think it is rather the input that he wants to iterate over, but $.each() should do.

Comment: @Anand I just updated my code (see my original post) but i get an error saying "don't make functions within a loop".  Any thoughts on the placement of my forloop?

Comment: just move your ajax call to another method and call it inside your loop. Also number will be declare outside for loop.